# IE spacing issue with table rows

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to add spacing to the bottom of rows in a table, and it works fine with Chrome.  But the spacing is not showing in IE 8.0

Any alternatives to the method used?

CSS

```
tr.spaceUnder > td
{
padding-bottom: 7px;
}
```

HTML

```
    <table width="105%">

            <tr class="spaceUnder">
                         <td><p>Friday, June 8th<br>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/357722824277712/" target="_blank" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('band','','images/awatson.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">Aaron Watson</a></p>
             </td>
             <td valign="bottom"><a href="http://www.ticketfly.com/event/122695/"><img src="http://www.bigtexassaloon.com/images/tix.png" border="0"></a>
                         </td>
                        </tr>

            <tr class="spaceUnder">
              <td>
                <p>Thursday,  June 14th<br>
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/180258595433140/" target="_blank" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('band','','images/acoustic.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">Five Man Jam</a><br />
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;Joe Blake<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;Neil Austin Imber<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;Eric Middleton<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;Stephen Chadwick<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;Ryan Lee Evans</p>
                           </td>
            </tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot if possible?

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare a doctype in your html?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: I added that and it spaced, however, now it's showing way too much spacing, and I'm not sure how to limit it to a certain amount.  Hre is a link to the site in question.  http://bigtexassaloon.com/clearlake.html  Issue is now in both Chrome and IE

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `>` character from the declaration `tr.spaceUnder > td`. It would be needed only if there were inner tables inside the cell (and even then, it would be better to restrict the effect in some other way).

In [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html), IE does not recognize such CSS3 selectors that use the `>` operator. Some old browsers do not recognize them in any mode. Avoid using them, when a simple alternative exists.

Your page probably lacks a doctype declaration or has a declaration that puts IE into Quirks Mode (e.g., HTML 4.01 Transitional doctype without a URL).

The page has a different browser compatibility issue as well, though you may have dealt with in CSS code that was not disclosed in the question. When you have a `p` element as the sole content of a `td` element, then some browsers suppress the normal default top and bottom margins for the `p` element, at least in Quirks Mode. Modern browsers in “standards mode” usually don’t do that, which means that there is considerable vertical spacing above and below the paragraph.

This can be handled by setting the margins for `p` explicitly in CSS. But markup like `<td><p>...</p></td>` normally serves no useful purpose, and the `p` markup is best omitted, avoiding the issue.